# How to typeset an equation with subscripts that has exponents

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I am trying to typeset

```
d_{t}= \mathcal{K}_{D,t}^{\alpha_D} h_{D,t}^{1-\alpha_D}
```

where the variables are `\mathcal{K}_{D,t}` and `h_{D,t}`, and `\alpha_D` is a parameter.

[image: Sample output]

The equation looks really messy, and the typesetting does not make it easy to read, or to distinguish the variable (with the subscripts) from the exponent (which is not part of the variable).

Any tips on how to better typeset this messy equation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add some brackets.  Ordinary round brackets around the terms would be best.  If you don't want to add these extra symbols to the equation then you can just use grouping writing `{K_{D,t}}^{\alpha_D}` etc., but this is not so clear.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  d_{t}= (\mathcal{K}_{D,t})^{\alpha_D} (h_{D,t})^{1-\alpha_D}
\end{displaymath}

\begin{displaymath}
  d_{t}= {\mathcal{K}_{D,t}}^{\alpha_D} {h_{D,t}}^{1-\alpha_D}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

For completeness, it has been suggested by Astrinus that another possibility it the last case is to move the superscript to be vertically above the `t`.  This avoids the appearance of `t` being raised to a power, however I still think the version with round brackets is clearest.

[image: Sample alternative output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  d_{t}= {\mathcal{K}_{D,\mathrlap{t}}}^{\alpha_D} {h_{D,\mathrlap{t}}}^{1-\alpha_D}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\llap`ing the "t" subscript could improve the second formula?

Comment: @Astrinus Given the OPs description of the "variables" I think that would just add to the confusion.  But you are right that one wishes to avoid readings these as powers of the `t`.  My main recommendation is the round brackets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast and helpful answer! @Astrinus: Does your comment concern only the equation in question, or would you change the display of the subscript in general? (say, in my paper)

Comment: @Christie This is only an opinion: in the second equation (the one without parentheses), I would move the superscript on the left, aligned with the comma. But I agree with Andrew Swann that the first version is better.

Comment: @Astrinus I have now added an example showing your suggestion.

Comment: Never remembered `\llap` and `\rlap` direction. Shame on me ;-) And yes, I agree with you: go on with the brackets!

Comment: @Christie I also recommend adding list-of-variables in the paper as well.